# Target already referenced by Autoscaler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm using Google Deployment Manager and I get this error when I create a new autoscaler with an instance group manager.

```
Unexpected response from resource of type compute.v1.autoscaler: 400
{
    "code": 400,
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "message": "Invalid value for field 'resource.target': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXX/zones/ZZZ/instanceGroupManagers/instance-group-manager'. Target already referenced by Autoscaler.",
            "reason": "invalid"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Invalid value for field 'resource.target': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXX/zones/ZZZ/instanceGroupManagers/instance-group-manager'. Target already referenced by Autoscaler.",
    "requestPath": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXX/zones/ZZZ/autoscalers",
    "statusMessage": "Bad Request"
}
```

I don't understand why, because the instance group manager is only referenced in one place, in the autoscaler configuration. Here is the config:

```
resources:
  - name: backend-igm
    type: compute.v1.instanceGroupManager
    properties:
      zone: ZZZ
      targetSize: 1
      baseInstanceName: backend-instance
      instanceTemplate: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXX/global/instanceTemplates/my-template

  - name: backend-as
    type: compute.v1.autoscaler
    properties:
      zone: ZZZ
      target: $(ref.backend-igm.selfLink)
      autoscalingPolicy:
        minNumReplicas: 1
        maxNumReplicas: 2
```

Besides, I've followed this tutorial in the first place: 
https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/create-advanced-http-load-balanced-deployment

And I can't see any difference that would explain this error.

Do you have any idea of what's going wrong?

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you were able to solve this, you can post the answer here for other community members who may be seeing this same issue. If not, can make sure the instance group referenced is the right one is not assigned to another autoscaler?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you might have created the autoscaler via Cloud Console or an API call, and then you're trying to use this autoscaler with the instance managed group created via the Deployment Manager.

If this is the case, when deploying resources via the Deployment Manager, it's best to deploy all the resources via the Deployment.